# Android layout with fixed button on bottom

Tags: android, xml

I have the following xml which is supposed to be something similar to [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEDk2.png)

The activity shows mostly ok, but i cant get the two down buttons to get fixed to the bottom of the screen without messing the top views.

I've tried to use a `FrameLayout` with two `RelativeLayouts`, alignment_bottom, an empty view with weight 1 between components and even still havent being able to accomplish my goal. Any help will be really appreciated, thank you in advance.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/group_info_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_below="@id/group_info_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/mainColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/descripcion"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/description_text"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/group_info_description"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/group_info_description"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/group_info_user_number"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

    <es.tretornesp.clickerchat.NonScrollableListView
        android:layout_below="@id/group_info_user_number"
        android:id="@+id/group_info_user_list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/borrar_grupo"
        android:background="@color/mainColor" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divisor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/salir"
        android:background="@color/mainColor"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which device(s) have you tried this on with the emulator?

Comment: Put the button outside of scrollview otherwise it will also scroll..

Comment: @Kwright02 my laptop cant run the emulator, i test via adb on bq aquaris m5 (api 25) and samsung note 8

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Edited, nice improvement, but it still has the same problem

Comment: what do you want? you want delete and exit group button aligned to the bottom or just entire linear layout aligned to the bottom ?

Comment: @faiiziiawan I have the two buttons (one with the attribute `View.GONE`) i need them to align bottom. I changed the file as _Saikrishna Rajaraman_ suggested and now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your layout file as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/exit_group">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/group_info_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitStart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/group_info_image"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="@string/descripcion"
                android:textColor="@color/mainColor"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/group_info_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/description_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="start"

                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/group_info_user_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/group_info_description"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <es.tretornesp.clickerchat.NonScrollableListView
                android:id="@+id/group_info_user_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/group_info_user_number"
                android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
                android:dividerHeight="1px" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/group_info_user_list"
                android:background="@color/mainColor"
                android:text="@string/borrar_grupo" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divisor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/delete_group"
                android:background="@color/grey" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/mainColor"
        android:text="@string/salir"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Tretorn Please add your "edit" as an additional answer, rather than modify the code in an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Coordinator Layout as a parent layout. like this.

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">


// your code 

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_contact_laksha_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="demo"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```